# Algorithm for determining the longest increasing subsequence?

Tags: algorithm, tree

This problem can be solved by making a BST from the given array of integers. Insertion in BST takes O(logn). So n insertions will take O(nlogn). And then longest subsequence can be derived by traversing only the rightmost children starting from root. This can take atmost O9n). Thus overall time complexty will be O(nlogn). Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Don't you just forget the original order of the elements in the process? How would this even be remotely correct?

Comment: @NiklasB If you don't rebalance the tree, its structure will reflect the original input order. But I'm not sure if that's enough to solve the problem. And it certainly wouldn't be O(n log n).

Comment: Juan, it won't reflect the input order! See my answer for a counterexample.

Comment: @EmilVikström Yes, you're right. So this approach makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 4):

No, the approach is not correct. Consider this tree:

```
    10
  2    11
 1 3
    4
```

Obviously the longest increasing subsequence here is `2,3,4` but your algorithm would give `10,11` which is shorter.

At the same time, there is no way of telling how my tree was built. Both these sequences would give the same tree:

```
10,2,1,3,4,11
10,11,2,1,3,4
```

These two have different longest increasing subsequences!